# Reproducing randomForest Proximity Matrix from R package in Python

Tags: python, r, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am trying to port this little piece of R code to python:

```
rf <- randomForest(features, proximity = T, oob.prox = T, ntree = 2000)
dists <- as.dist(1 - rf$proximity)
```

with parameters
`oob.prox`: Should proximity be calculated only on “out-of-bag” data?
`proximity`: if `proximity=TRUE` when `randomForest` is called, a matrix of proximity measures among the input (based on the frequency that pairs of data points are in the same terminal nodes).

I am currently trying using `sklearn.ensemble.RandomTreesEmbedding` for this task, however there is no functionality for the proximity matrix. I found the following developer comment though:

> We don't implement proximity matrix in Scikit-Learn (yet).
> However, this could be done by relying on the apply function provided
> in our implementation of decision trees. That is, for all pairs of
> samples in your dataset, iterate over the decision trees in the forest
> (through forest.estimators_) and count the number of times they fall
> in the same leaf, i.e., the number of times apply give the same node
> id for both samples in the pair.

And so I tried, utilizing numpy's `pdist()` function along with my custom distance (or in this case, proximity) measure. I still have several problems:

1. The proximity function is outstandingly slow
2. How to handle the out-of-bag behaviour
3. How to recreate the exact behaviour of `as.dist(1- rf$proximity)`: I think I need to normalize my count matrix, then subtract it from 1 and then afterwards compute the euclidean distances between its rows!?

My code as of now looks like this:

```
# grow a random forest from points
rf = ensemble.RandomTreesEmbedding(n_estimators=200, 
    random_state=0,
    max_depth=5
)
rfdata = rf.fit_transform(xdata);


# define an affinity measure function to use with numpy's pdist
def treeprox(u, v):
    leafcount = 0
    # needs reshaping for single samples
    u = u.reshape(1,-1)
    v = v.reshape(1,-1)
    a = rf.apply(u)
    b = rf.apply(v)
    # count number of times they fall in the same leaf 
    # (use of np forces element-wise)
    c = np.sum(np.array(a)==np.array(b))
    return c
 
distm = pdist(xdata, proxfun)
distm = squareform(distm)
```

There must be a better way I guess, since this functionality is readily provided by the R package `randomForest`.
Any suggestions?
tia

Comment: I am just starting looking into the same task. There is a similar question in SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25090773/unsupervised-random-forest-proximities-in-python? Do you have any updates?

Comment: above code is what I have and what technically works, but it is unusable slow. I think the only solution here would be to dig into the actual sklearn.ensemble.RandomTreesEmbedding module and figure out a neat way to build the matrix at runtime (e.g. how it's happening in R). Don't think I will get around to do this soon...

Comment: OK, I intend to do something similar and will update the SO post. FYI, I think np.count_nonzero() is faster than np.sum()

Answer (score 2):

I have written some code for this. It can be found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/270201/pooling-levels-of-categorical-variables-for-regression-trees/). In answer to your specific questions:

1. I have tried to optimize for speed. What I did should be a little faster than the code above.
2. I do not use out of bag records. In fact the original documentation does not suggest this. I created another [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/274857/proximity-matrix-should-i-include-in-bag-records) to see if the consequences are understood.
3. This is handled in my code by normalizing by the total possible leaves that could be matched.

Comment: have you tested speed yours against mine?
with my dataset of dimension about (3500,340) even using 500 trees took a whole night!

Comment: I could not get your implementation running. What is proxfun? I do that in about 1 hour. I actually made a ticket about making it faster and cut out the slow part. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43621977/build-matrix-without-loops/43623106 Maybe add your solution in the format for that question.

Comment: On 3500 rows for 500 trees it takes 23 seconds if I include the time it takes to train the tree

Comment: c&p mistake; it's the treeprox function. u mean my code takes 23 seconds? have you tested it with 340 variables?

Comment: No mine took 23s. I only have 30 input variables. I am not sure that this would change the call time of apply() much so it may not matter much. If update with a toy example of working code Ill see what the time for yours takes. Otherwise try mine, note that the prox matrix in mine can be calculated for any categorical variable.